# How to create a bootable usb pen to install windows, now that you cant use FAT32?

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, formatting, windows-installation

My old method was simple. Get a large USB stick.

If necessary: use gparted in Linux to create a partition table. Either msdos or gpt.
Create a FAT32 partition and use a Windows machine and Universal Usb Installer https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ .

I get the ISO image from the Microsoft website currently this one: Win10_20H2_EnglishInternational_x64.iso

Now I noticed that one of the files inside the newer ISO is bigger than 4GB so FAT32 can no longer be used.

So my question is. What procedure should I use? My machine has UEFI boot enabled and my HDD are UEFI.

MBR GPT - NTFS ?
MBR MSDOS - NTFS ?

Which apps or commands should I use to create the bootable USB?

PS: I'm also seeing a "missing driver required" that I never saw before when trying to install Windows10 in this same machine.

Comment: You can extract the edition you want from the .wim file. This will significantly decrease the size of the .wim file.  This can be done with DISM.  An alternative solution is to use Rufus since your going to use flash storage.  The linked instructions are unnecessary with Rufus and are out of date.

Comment: Pretty sure they just use ExFAT these days. On Mac, the Boot Camp loader was updated to allow Win install from ExFAT. (I've never done it on an actual 'Win PC' to test)

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Windows Media Creation Tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-installation-media-for-windows-99a58364-8c02-206f-aa6f-40c3b507420d) to create a bootable Windows installation on your USB drive.